# Finding a Linear Transformation which satisfy some given conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Define a linear operator $\ T: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ such that satisfy simultaneously the following conditions. $$ \operatorname{Ker}(T) \cap \operatorname{Im}(T) = \operatorname{Span}\{(1,1,1,1)\}  \\ (1,5,1,0) \in \operatorname{Im}(T) \\ (3,1,2,2) \notin \operatorname{Im}(T) + \operatorname{Ker}(T)$$

I am having problems with the first and third condition
.
In the first, I'm not sure how to make $\operatorname{Ker}(T) \cap \operatorname{Im}(T) \subseteq \operatorname{Span}\{(1,1,1,1)\}$

With respect to the third, I have no idea. What I was about to do, is to define T and hopefully it will check the requested thing, and if it doesn't try with another T. I am sure it must be a more efficient way to do it, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 1):

Here is such a matrix:

$$T:=\begin{bmatrix}
1  &  -1 &  1  &  -1\\
1  &  -5  & 5  &  -1\\
1  &  -1 &  1  &  -1\\
1  &  0  &  0  &  -1\end{bmatrix}$$

The range of $T$ is clearly generated by its first and second columns $U_1$ and $U_2$: $Im(T)= Span(U_1,U_2)$, with $-U_2=(1,5,1,0)^T \in range(T)$ as desired.

The nullspace of $T$ is obtained without difficulty (by solving TX=0) as $Ker(T)=Span(U_1,U_3)$ with

$$U_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\end{bmatrix} \ \ U_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$Ker(T) \cap Im(T) = Span(U_1) = Span((1,1,1,1)^T) \ \ \text{as desired}$$

$$Im(T)+Ker(T)=Span({U_1,U_2,U_3})$$

and $U_4:=(3,1,2,2)^T \notin Im(T)+Ker(T)$ (as desired) because the rank of matrix $D:=[U_1|U_2|U_3|U_4]$ is 4 (because $det(D)\neq0$).